# How to solve this question in mysql workbranch trriggers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

when in try the code in the image, get an error that there is average table(that there is no a temporary table in the database northwind) ...
I understand that the problem is because there is no table average... in the database Northwind,  but how can I connect it in java? what should write more in my code?

[java ...link image to my code in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncwVG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery `(select e.EmployeeID from employees e)` will get all ID from table employees , which then makes all employees matching them get their rows wiped out.
In triggers , we can use keyword OLD and NEW to present the corresponding rows in the original table. In this case, using OLD is suitable. Also ,  use the = operator instead of IN as MySQL trigger is working in a row by row process due to the FOR EACH ROW part .

```
DELIMITER // 
create trigger removeEmployee before delete on employees for each row begin
delete FROM employeeterritories  where employeeId = OLD.EmployeeID; 
end //
```

Comment: i try it , but when i try to delete a employee get this error!  delete from employees where EmployeeID=1
 this error :- Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'employeeterritories' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Interesting, mine worked . Could you provide detailed information regarding your two tables.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Employees` (
    `EmployeeID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `LastName` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `FirstName` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `Title` VARCHAR(30),
    `TitleOfCourtesy` VARCHAR(25),
    `BirthDate` DATETIME,
    `HireDate` DATETIME,
    `Address` VARCHAR(60),
    `City` VARCHAR(15),

Comment: `Region` VARCHAR(15),
    `PostalCode` VARCHAR(10),
    `Country` VARCHAR(15),
    `HomePhone` VARCHAR(24),
    `Extension` VARCHAR(4),
    `Photo` LONGBLOB,
    `Notes` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    `ReportsTo` INTEGER,
    `PhotoPath` VARCHAR(255),
     `Salary` FLOAT,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_Employees` PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`)
);

Comment: this the second table

Comment: CREATE TABLE `EmployeeTerritories` (
    `EmployeeID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `TerritoryID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_EmployeeTerritories` PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`, `TerritoryID`)
);

Comment: The tables appear fine . Just make sure you have successfully modified your trigger like displayed above. SHOW TRIGGERS

Comment: Have you found anything suspicious ? Please let me know if further assitance is required.

Comment: There no anything new, i'm in the same error

Comment: Sadly I can not open the link to your image probably due to some internet regulations. Could you please copy and paste the messages ?

Comment: when i try to do this quarey:-  delete from employees where employeeID = 1 ,  then get this  error:- You can't specify target table 'employeeterritories' for update in FROM clause

Comment: If this is a lab scenario can you drop the trigger and try the DELETE statement again ?

Comment: get this error, i thought it's due that there connection between two tables with the key (employeeID)

Comment: Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`northwind`.`employeeterritories`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EmployeeTerritories_Employees` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`) REFERENCES `employees` (`EmployeeID`))

Comment: So it's the foreign key to blame.  In this case, you don't really need the trigger to do the job. Just modify the foreign key with  ON DELETE CASCADE  for the  table employeeterritories. Then mysql will remove records automatically from the child-related tables when the main parental table data is deleted.

Comment: Please let me know if the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

[this the error i get when try to delete the employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDLrw.png)

this the error i get when try to delete the employee:-
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'employeeterritories' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Prefer edit your question than post an answer of it because it's not an answer